How are bubbles created inside the CPU?
Suppose we have a CPU which uses pipelining.One way for the efficiency to be reduced is if a bubble is created (e.g the cpu cannot fetch or decode a instruction)which delays the instruction execution cycle of all instructions in queue.But how are these bubbles created in the first place?How can the cpu be unable to fetch or decode a instruction?Thanks

There are a few reasons why, in an in-order pipeline, an instruction may need to be delayed by one or more cycles. Some examples:

There is a read after write hazard, so the read must be delayed.
The instruction text might be a cache or TLB miss, so bubbles are inserted into the pipeline while the miss is resolved.
A mispredicted branch may cause the instructions after the branch to be turned into bubbles while the correct branch target is loaded.
An instruction caused a trap/exception, so all instructions after the trapping instruction need to be turned into bubbles while the exception handler is loaded into the pipeline.


Ahh okay thanks a lot.One more question.Every reason here creates the bubble  when the instruction tries to be executed not when it is fetched or decoded  right?

An instruction cache miss would be a bubble created by instruction fetch, no?

Yes you are correct

The NOP instruction, which means no operation, is an instruction to implement a bubble.
When this happens, the datapath in each stage of the pipelined processor with the bubble would not perform any computation. E.g., the ALU does not perform a logical or arithmetic operation when it is in the bubble/NOP state.
